# embedding responsive video player to web page using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video

I have following code snippet to responsive embed video to web page.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 " style="display:table-cell;margin-top:20px;" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="videoUiWrapper thumbnail">
            <video width="100%" id="vdHotPress" controls>
            <!-- set width to 100% and add controls for play and volume buttons-->

                <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTFpAL7Rfww" type="video/mp4" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Video player is displayed. But video player is disabled. What would be the reason for this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to use the Youtube iframe embed instead of the HTML5 video embed. The source you are trying to use is not the URL of the video itself, but a Youtube page. Try this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LTFpAL7Rfww" ></iframe>
</div>
```